# Change column values depending on other column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have problem with my data frame.

I have a dataframe with 2 columns, 'word' and 'word_categories'. I created different variables which include the different words, e.g. 'noun' which includes all the nouns of the word column. I now want to change the labels in the word_categories column to the corresponding variable. So if the word in the word column is included in the object 'noun', I want the word_categories column to display 'noun'.

```
df <- read.csv("palm.csv")
noun <- c("house", ...)
adj <- c("hard", ...)
...
```

The data frame looks like the following. It includes other columns but they are fine.

```
word  word_categories
house
car
hard
...
```

I now want to look, if the words are in any of the created objects and if so, I want the corresponding label printed in the word_categories column. So for 'house' the column should show noun, for 'hard' it should show adjective. If the word is in none of the objects, it should show nothing or 'NA'.

I tried it with the following:

```
palm$word_categories <- ifelse(palm$word == noun, "noun",
             ifelse(palm$word == adj, "adjective", "")))
```

This, however, doesn't work at all and I have 7 Objects in total so the statement becomes ridiculously long. How do I do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

If the dataframe is called `palm` (you first call it `df` but later you use `palm`) and `noun` and `adj` are vectors as you define above, I would do:

```
library(dplyr)
palm <- palm %>%
    mutate(word_categories = case_when(word %in% noun ~ "noun",
                                       word %in% adj ~ "adjective",
                                       TRUE ~ NA_character_))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a named vector of your noun/adjective dictionaries to select each element. The name would be the word and the corresponding data would be noun, adjective etc. You didn't really supply any data so I made some up.

```
df <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
         word = c("dog", "short", "bird", "cat", "short", "man")
)



nounName <- c('dog', 'cat', 'bird')
adjName <- c('quick', 'brown', 'short')

noun <- rep('noun', length(nounName))
adj <- rep('adjective', length(adjName))
names(noun) <- nounName
names(adj) <- adjName

partsofspeech <- c(noun, adj)

df$word_categories <- partsofspeech[df$word]
```